# Reducing the lines of code based on conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 if conditions, but with this line of code is getting increased. Can I reduce some code so that it works the same as it is now.

```
if (ddlProject.SelectedValue != "0" && ddlBuilding.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
        string queryInsert;
        DataTable dtval = new DataTable();
        dtval = CF.ExecuteDT("Select BOOKING_NO from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL where project_id = '" + ddlProject.SelectedValue + "' and building_id = '" + ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + "'");

        for (int i = 0; i < dtval.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string StrSeq = CF.ExecuteScaler("Select xxcus.xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_SEQ.next_val from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL");
            queryInsert = "Insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h select '" + StrSeq + "', SYSDATE FROM xxacl_pn_leases_all where booking_no = '" + dtval.Rows[i]["BOOKING_NO"].ToString() + "'";
            OracleConnection conUpdate = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
            OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand();
            string allQueryUpdate = queryInsert;
            cmd1.CommandText = allQueryUpdate;
            cmd1.Connection = conUpdate;
            conUpdate.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        string queryUpdate;
        queryUpdate = "update xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL set ASSIGNED_TO = '" + ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue + "'";

        OracleConnection conUpdate1 = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
        OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand();
        string allQueryUpdate1 = queryUpdate;
        cmd2.CommandText = allQueryUpdate1;
        cmd2.Connection = conUpdate1;
        conUpdate1.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record updated successfully');window.location ='FrmHoldingCoordinateUpdate.aspx?Redirect=" + Request.QueryString["Redirect"] + "&userid=" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "';", true);        
    }
    if (ddlProject.SelectedValue != "0" && ddlBuilding.SelectedValue == "0")
    {
        string queryInsert;
        DataTable dtval = new DataTable();
        dtval = CF.ExecuteDT("Select BOOKING_NO from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL where project_id = '" + ddlProject.SelectedValue + "' and building_id = '" + ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + "'");

        for (int i = 0; i < dtval.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string StrSeq = CF.ExecuteScaler("Select xxcus.xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_SEQ.next_val from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL");
            queryInsert = "Insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h select '" + StrSeq + "', SYSDATE FROM xxacl_pn_leases_all where booking_no = '" + dtval.Rows[i]["BOOKING_NO"].ToString() + "'";
            OracleConnection conUpdate = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
            OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand();
            string allQueryUpdate = queryInsert;
            cmd1.CommandText = allQueryUpdate;
            cmd1.Connection = conUpdate;
            conUpdate.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        string queryUpdate;
        queryUpdate = "update xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL set ASSIGNED_TO = '" + ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue + "'";

        OracleConnection conUpdate1 = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
        OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand();
        string allQueryUpdate1 = queryUpdate;
        cmd2.CommandText = allQueryUpdate1;
        cmd2.Connection = conUpdate1;
        conUpdate1.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record updated successfully');window.location ='FrmHoldingCoordinateUpdate.aspx?Redirect=" + Request.QueryString["Redirect"] + "&userid=" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "';", true);        
    }
```

**Just I am checking the conditions.Rest code is same**

Comment: In what purpose are the conditions checked?

Comment: @owczarek: first, if both the dropdownlist are selected and second only one dropdownlist is selected. Project will always be selected, it cant be 0

Comment: Start using (private) methods; the code will become more readable.

Comment: @JeroenHeier: Ok, will do that. But how to deal with these two conditions. any help ?

Comment: I might be missing something. What the difference between the code in the two IF blocks ?

Comment: @AshutoshVyas: in first both ddl is not equal to `0` and in send one of the ddl is equal to `0`.

Comment: Thats the condition! What is the difference in code of IF blocks?

Comment: If there is no difference inside the `if`s just make one check: `ddlProject.SelectedValue != "0"`. The second condition make no sense in this case.

Comment: Let me reframe. Remove both the IF Blocks and simply use the code that you have in either of the IF blocks. That single code block would work fine for both conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compared the code written in both the if statements using winMerge tool. There is absolutely no difference of even a single bit. You should simply create a private method to enable code reuse in your module. This is how it might look. Without doubt still more refactoring can be done even in the new function `UpdateDatabase` that I've written to align it to the principles of [clean-code](http://blog.cleancoder.com/).

```
if (ddlProject.SelectedValue != "0" && ddlBuilding.SelectedValue != "0")
{
   UpdateDatabase();      
}

if (ddlProject.SelectedValue != "0" && ddlBuilding.SelectedValue == "0")
{
    UpdateDatabase();       
}

private void UpdateDatabase()
{
       string queryInsert;
        DataTable dtval = new DataTable();
        dtval = CF.ExecuteDT("Select BOOKING_NO from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL where project_id = '" + ddlProject.SelectedValue + "' and building_id = '" + ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + "'");

        for (int i = 0; i < dtval.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string StrSeq = CF.ExecuteScaler("Select xxcus.xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_SEQ.next_val from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL");
            queryInsert = "Insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h select '" + StrSeq + "', SYSDATE FROM xxacl_pn_leases_all where booking_no = '" + dtval.Rows[i]["BOOKING_NO"].ToString() + "'";
            OracleConnection conUpdate = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
            OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand();
            string allQueryUpdate = queryInsert;
            cmd1.CommandText = allQueryUpdate;
            cmd1.Connection = conUpdate;
            conUpdate.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        string queryUpdate;
        queryUpdate = "update xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL set ASSIGNED_TO = '" + ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue + "'";

        OracleConnection conUpdate1 = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
        OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand();
        string allQueryUpdate1 = queryUpdate;
        cmd2.CommandText = allQueryUpdate1;
        cmd2.Connection = conUpdate1;
        conUpdate1.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record updated successfully');window.location ='FrmHoldingCoordinateUpdate.aspx?Redirect=" + Request.QueryString["Redirect"] + "&userid=" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "';", true);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon the above answer, I do not see a need for multiple IF conditions either.

```
if (ddlProject.SelectedValue != "0")
{
   UpdateDatabase();      
}

private void UpdateDatabase()
{
       string queryInsert;
        DataTable dtval = new DataTable();
        dtval = CF.ExecuteDT("Select BOOKING_NO from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL where project_id = '" + ddlProject.SelectedValue + "' and building_id = '" + ddlBuilding.SelectedValue + "'");

        for (int i = 0; i < dtval.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string StrSeq = CF.ExecuteScaler("Select xxcus.xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_SEQ.next_val from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL");
            queryInsert = "Insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h select '" + StrSeq + "', SYSDATE FROM xxacl_pn_leases_all where booking_no = '" + dtval.Rows[i]["BOOKING_NO"].ToString() + "'";
            OracleConnection conUpdate = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
            OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand();
            string allQueryUpdate = queryInsert;
            cmd1.CommandText = allQueryUpdate;
            cmd1.Connection = conUpdate;
            conUpdate.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        string queryUpdate;
        queryUpdate = "update xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL set ASSIGNED_TO = '" + ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue + "'";

        OracleConnection conUpdate1 = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
        OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand();
        string allQueryUpdate1 = queryUpdate;
        cmd2.CommandText = allQueryUpdate1;
        cmd2.Connection = conUpdate1;
        conUpdate1.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record updated successfully');window.location ='FrmHoldingCoordinateUpdate.aspx?Redirect=" + Request.QueryString["Redirect"] + "&userid=" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "';", true);        
}
```